# Schema, table and column names processing via custom migration class with Fluent Migrator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluent-migrator

I'm writing a migration tool for modular applications which are intended to use internal modules, each with its own set of migrations.

Our applications are all based on dotnet core, may use different dbms and can use different conventions: each module in its own schema or not, custom table prefix per module, upper or lower case table names, etc.

Thus these conventions need to be told by the application itself while needing to write only once each migration in each module.

I'd like not to have to call a method call each time we insert a column name, table name, etc, for the developer not to have to have all this stuff in mind.

I started to reimplement each expression builder, but I feel it's very wrong and error-prone.

I also made a custom generic `Migration` class, inheriting Migration and having a naming convention interface as a generic type (which as three methods to transform schema, table, and columns), in order to register and resolve it with the service collection and use it to built SQL queries. I think this is the right approach.

I also made a method that can handle every kind of expression type to apply the transformations, but I'm stuck at this point and don't know where to call it.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong, is there any way I can accomplish what I want?
Thank you for your help. (also, sorry, I'm on my phone, and don't have a pc nor the code right now, but this is making me crazy).

**Edit**: At first I wanted to use Conventions, which seemed to be exactly what I wanted, but it doesn't handle table names, and looks like it cannot be specific to a set of migrations. However, the place where they are applied may be where I need to apply mine, but I haven't found a way to overload the `Apply` method: the `MigrationValidator` that contains the convension doesn't implement any interface and so I cannot revolve it by the dependency injections.

Comment: I see that my question don't inspire a lot of people :-D I guess I'll have to scratch my head a little bit more on Monday!

Comment: it would be easier to understand the issue having a more detailed explanation of the issue, e.g. maybe with some code and examples